# What might be the reason of intermittent NoClassDefFoundError ？

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, apache-zeppelin

I am using hive jdbc to query hive data, and I run it several times with same input and same environment, but unfortunately, sometimes it will through NoClassDefFoundError, but sometimes it succeed. I am confused what might cause this kind of intermittent NoClassDefFoundError

```
Results:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation$AuthenticationMethod
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.security.JDBCSecurityImpl.getAuthType(JDBCSecurityImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.isKerboseEnabled(JDBCInterpreter.java:261)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.KerberosInterpreter.close(KerberosInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.close(JDBCInterpreter.java:352)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:836)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(ParallelScheduler.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: One possibility is intermittent failure of class initialization for that class, or some other class that depends on it.  Check the logs for **earlier** exceptions from the initialization failure.

Comment: Another possibility might be the mentioned class having static initializers which could fail while loading?  But one would hope to see some earlier errors then too.

Comment: That's what I mean by class initialization.  (An unchecked exception thrown during initialization of `static` variables, or during execution of static initializer blocks.)